# How to page between modal data in ng-repeat & angular ui modals

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

New to Angular JS and had a pretty pedestrian question. I have an ng-repeat that populates some data via a local JSON file, and when clicked, brings up some more detailed information about the specified company. What i want to do now is give the user the ability to "page" between each company, using either arrows on the screen or keyboard arrows (like most photo like boxes).

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="portfolio" class="showcase-list stripe" ng-controller="portfolio" id="stripe-showcase">
<div class="contain">
    <h3>Our Companies</h3>
    <a ng-repeat="co in companies" href="#{{co.name}}" class="showcase" ng-click="open(co)">
        <div class="image" id="{{co.name}}">
            <span class="helper"></span>
                <img class="displayed" src="{{co.logo}}">
            <div class="caption">

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--MODAL WINDOW-->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <img class="displayed lightbox" src="{{co.logo}}">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ co.investor_description }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </script>
    </a>
    <div id="{{co.name}}" class="flipbox-dialog"><p>{{co.investor_description}}</p></div>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, co) {
    console.log("that");
    $scope.co = co;
});

app.controller('portfolio', function($scope, $timeout, $modal) {

$scope.companies = [{
    "investor_description": "Apportable\u2019s platform allows iOS applications to run on Android devices automatically, without requiring extensive changes to the original Objective-C or C++ code.",
    "name": "Apportable",
    "logo": "http://api-images.crunchbase.com/assets/images/resized/0018/5576/185576v7-max-450x450.png",
    "url": "http://www.apportable.com/",
    "linkedin_url": null,
    "crunchbase_url": "http://www.crunchbase.com/company/apportable",
    "angellist_url": "https://angel.co/apportable",
    "twitter_url": "http://twitter.com/apportable"
}, {
    "investor_description": "Your Personalized English-Speaking School\r\n\r\nSpeed towards English fluency with 24/7 online conversation classes and 1-on-1 SpeakAssist study program",
    "name": "Colingo",
    "logo": "http://www.m.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/colingo_logo.png",
    "url": "http://www.colingo.com",
    "linkedin_url": "",
    "crunchbase_url": "http://www.crunchbase.com/company/colingo",
    "angellist_url": "https://angel.co/colingo",
    "twitter_url": "https://twitter.com/colingo"
}, {
    "investor_description": "DataTorrent Inc builds technology that enables next generation, real-time big data applications on Hadoop.",
    "name": "DataTorrent",
    "logo": "http://www.m.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Datatorrent-logo.png",
    "url": "http://www.datatorrent.com",
    "linkedin_url": "http://www.linkedin.com/company/malhar-inc-",
    "crunchbase_url": "http://www.crunchbase.com/company/datatorrent",
    "angellist_url": "https://angel.co/datatorrent",
    "twitter_url": "http://twitter.com/datatorrent"
}];

$scope.open = function (_co) {
    console.log("this");
    var modalInstance = $modal.open(
        {
            controller: "ModalInstanceCtrl",
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            resolve: {
                co: function () {
                    return _co;
                }
            }
        });
};
});
```

Not really sure where to begin here....Can someone please point me in the right direction?? I'd be very much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try specifying your 'prev' & 'next' buttons and values in your JS  as simple links...

and or create 'prev' & 'next' buttons in myModalContent.html

hope this is of some help.